# Analog voltage control via Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, analog, motor-controller, dac, digital-potentiometer

I have a BLDC motor driver that's powered at 24v DC. The control for this driver is via a line that modulates speed based on the voltage applied (between 0 and 24v) so a voltage divider using a pot seems like the simplest solution that works flawlessly for testing.

Now to actually implement this, what would be the best way to do this with a microcontroller? Using a DAC or a digital pot seems like a simple solution but options are limited at those voltage levels. Current requirements for the control line are low (10ma or less).

Comment: are you certain that the driver does not have digital control input?

Comment: Yep, 4 wire driver, pwr, gnd, control and tacho

Comment: 0 to 24 seems odd... You have a spec sheet that says that? Most things analog are 0-10V, 0 to 5V, or 4-20mA current signals...

Comment: Surprisingly enough, it is. I tested it out under multiple conditions too. It takes full range input of 0 to Vss. In my case, the motor is rated for 24v hence the 0-24 range.

Answer (score 4):

If your microcontroller does not have a DAC, you can generate high-frequency pwm, run it through a low pass filter and it is effectively an analog voltage.

Unfortunately if you're trying to get up to a higher rail voltage than your microcontroller pin output, then you could either first pwm a transistor in front of the filter with a pull down from a higher voltage rail, or use an op-amp after your filter.

A pull up to drive a filter on 24V will eat a lot of power, you might be better off using an op-amp amplifier out of a DAC or 0-5V PWM run through a low pass filter... Below is a schematic to give an idea, although you will notice if you simulate it is more like 0-22V due to the 4.7k pullup resistor not driving the filter well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffZK03.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use a DAC followed by a non-inverting op-amp based amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with controlling the motor with a transistor driven by a PWM signal

Comment: It's a brushless motor and OP already has a driver

Comment: I think MadHatter and Scott are suggesting using filtered PWM in lieu of a DAC.